# Should I throttle my Ubuntu server that is on my home network?

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-12.04, webserver, bandwidth, home-server

I have just set up one of my old computers to be a web-server with Ubuntu 12.04.3. I was thinking that i should probably throttle/limit the bandwidth/speeds over ssh/ftp in order to not murder my internet at home when the server is being accessed. Ive got Comcast internet 28mbps down 5mbps up. I probably wont set throttling up unless the server starts bogging down my internet but if some one could tell me how would I go about throttling it for ssh and ftp connections.

Comment: I wouldn't bother unless it's actually affecting something. I run a webserver at home, and the only time when my internet at home gets affected is when someone downloads a big file from my home server, which was almost never.

Comment: ill go ahead and try w/o throttling first then. Could you tell me how to set it up in case I decide to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it.

1) you can do it directly by acting on your program. For instance, with *ProFTPd*, insert this line

```
   TransferRate RETR,STOR,APPE,STOU 1000
```

in the file /etc/proftpd.conf. This will limit bandwidth to 1000 kB/s. The same thing cannot be done with *ssh* though, which has always been meant for interactive sessions, not background downloads.

2) You can use *tc* (=Traffic Control, appropriately). I have little experience with it, I can just point you to this [fine Introduction](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-traffic-shaping-ftp-server-port-21-22/) to the topic. I find this solution too *ad hoc* for my tastes, and too difficult to port, but of course you may differ, so do take a look at it.

3) You can use QoS (=Quality of Service) in your router. You will have to find a voice QoS in your GUI, and see the specifics. It will allow you to set limits depending on MAC address or application (you can define a new application as you wish, if the one you want to throttle is not already in the list), but **not** the two simultaneously. This means that if you throttle ftp this way, it will be throttled for *all* pcs on your LAN. If you want to evade this constrain, you will have to set up a VLAN  or a DMZ (which might be a good idea anyway, security-wise), in which you place only your server.

As ever, YMMV.